# Select text of textEdit object with QTextCursor, QTextEdit

Tags: python, qt, pyqt4

I have a textEdit field and I want to process some selected text within this field (but not the format of it).

So far, I connect the button with:

QtCore.QObject.connect(self.ui.mytext_button,QtCore.SIGNAL("clicked()"), self.mytext)

The method:

```
def mytext(s):
     return s.upper()
```

But how do I tell Python that s is the selected text? I know that is something with  selectionStart(), selectionEnd(). And how to change it to what mytext returns? I think is something with insertText(), but here I am also lost at the details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering my own question. Posting here for fellow Python noobs:

Get the selected text:

```
cursor = self.ui.editor_window.textCursor()
textSelected = cursor.selectedText()
```

insert back the text into your editor.

```
self.ui.editor_window.append(s)
```

There are also alternatives to append(), for inserting the text into the original text.
So, to put a selected text into uppercase:

```
def mytext(self):
        cursor = self.ui.editor_window.textCursor()
        textSelected = cursor.selectedText()
        s = textSelected.upper()
        self.ui.editor_window.append(s)
```